# Avoiding duplicates and assigning value to each singleton in a for loop

Tags: python, loops

I am attempting to deal with the duplication and the failure of assigning value to each singleton in a for loop.

First, I create edges from one node to nodes which it connects to:

```
ti = "D" #node from
lst = ["A", "B", "C"] #nodes to

packaged = [(ti, l) for l in lst]  # a list of edges (from - to)

l_lst = len(lst)  ## length of lst, *i.e.* degree of ti

weight = 1 / float(l_lst)  # edge weight, normalized by length of lst

for pair in packaged:
    print (packged, weight)
```

This gives me

```
([('D', 'A'), ('D', 'B'), ('D', 'C')], 0.3333333333333333)
([('D', 'A'), ('D', 'B'), ('D', 'C')], 0.3333333333333333)
([('D', 'A'), ('D', 'B'), ('D', 'C')], 0.3333333333333333)
```

However, what I would like to achieve is:

```
('D', 'A'), 0.3333333333333333
('D', 'B'), 0.3333333333333333
('D', 'C'), 0.3333333333333333
```

How to avoid duplicates and assign weight to each pair of nodes (edge)?

Thank you!!

Comment: Um: `print(pair, weight)` ?

Comment: You're printing `packaged` on each iteration - are you supposed to be printing `pair` instead?

Comment: Haha. Thanks!! I totally confused myself.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is this:

```
ti = "D" #node from
lst = ["A", "B", "C"] #nodes to

packaged = [(ti, l) for l in lst]  # a list of edges (from - to)

l_lst = len(lst)  ## length of lst, *i.e.* degree of ti

weight = 1 / float(l_lst)  # edge weight, normalized by length of lst

for pair in packaged:
    print (pair, weight)
```

In for loop use `pair` instead of `packaged`

Answer (score 3):

A simple fix:

```
for pair in packaged:
    print (pair, weight)
```